# Flutter - Separate function for each Tab in TabBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make News app in Flutter, for now I only have two tabs for two news categories.

The way it works is I have Provider function which gets data from news website, I pass in arguments (url and other) to that function depending on category.

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var newsListRepo = Provider.of<NewsListRepo>(context);
    List<Widget> categories = [VestiList(), SportList()];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: categories.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Novinarnica'),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'Vesti'),
                  Tab(text: 'Sport'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabContent(
            categories: categories,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TabContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> categories;

  const TabContent({Key key, this.categories}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBarView(
      children: categories,
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in categories list I have two other screens, which contain ListView filled with articles of that category. In each of those I have:

```
didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    Provider.of<NewsListRepo>(context).getData(
         href: blicVestiHref,
      image: blicVestiImage,
      title: blicVestiTitle,
      url: blicVestiUrl,);
  }
```

And..

```
 didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    Provider.of<NewsListRepo>(context).getData(
        href: blicSportHref,
      image: blicSportImage,
      title: blicSportTitle,
      url: blicSportUrl,);
  }
```

I'm calling same fucntion, with different arguments, but in TabBar im getting same stuff.

So in case you're confused. I'll make shorter question. How do I make TabBar where content of each Tab can call it's own function?

Comment: I had a similar problem and found a solution, I posted it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099852/changing-tab-does-not-rebuild-list/67169859#67169859